# Python data list issue

Tags: python, list, error-handling

Working on a custom lists class in python like

```
class ListData:
        def __init__(self):
                 self.data = []

        def add(self, x):
                 self.data.append(x)

        def delete(self, x):
                 self.data.remove(x)
```

When testing, always return None :

```
from list import ListData

listdata = ListData()


mylist = [34, 32, 34, 89]
mylist = listdata.add(2)
mylist = listdata.add(5)

print mylist # Prints None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your API to be able to print it as a list. you may read the following

[Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python)

```
class ListData:
        def __init__(self):
                 self.data = []

        def add(self, x):
                 self.data.append(x)

        def delete(self, x):
                 self.data.remove(x)

        def data(self):
            return self.data




a = ListData()
a.add(1)
a.add(2)
print a.data
```

will output:

> > > [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the `add` and `delete` methods, so assigning their return values to `mylist` leaves you with `None`. Get rid of the extra assignments and your code will work.

```
mylist = [34, 32, 34, 89]
listdata.add(2)
listdata.add(5)

print mylist
```

Alternatively you could modify the methods to return `self`, though there's not much value in doing so.

```
def add(self, x):
    self.data.append(x)
    return self

def delete(self, x):
    self.data.remove(x)
    return self
```